# Setting up Log shipping without enabling LS copy job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping

We have a need where we need to set up LS for the servers where we use NAS for backups.

As NAS is shared between Primary and Secondary there will not be a need to use LS COpy job as backups will be duplicated and LS might not work

How can i set up with just LS backup and LS restore configured and make LS a success?

Answer (score 2):

Setup log shipping and disable LS copy job.
As long as you setup backup folder correctly you should be ok.